# How to properly use pitch_shift (librosa)?

Tags: python, audio, librosa, pitch-shifting

I try to use the librosa and pitch_shift from librosa.
I recorded some my voice and used this code:

```
sampling_rate= 44100
y, sr = librosa.load(directory, sr=sampling_rate) # y is a numpy array of the wav file, sr = sample rate

y_shifted = librosa.effects.pitch_shift(y, sr, n_steps=4, bins_per_octave=24)  # shifted by 4 half steps
librosa.output.write_wav(directory, y_shifted, sr=sampling_rate, norm=False)
```

It works fine - almost.

I hear some noise in my new voice (after pitch_shifting)

Is there something what I need to use?

Without shift:

https://vocaroo.com/i/s1qEEDvzcUHN

With shift (n_steps = 4):

https://vocaroo.com/i/s0cOiC0cFJSB

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pitch-shifting typically involves an [STFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-time_Fourier_transform#Discrete-time_STFT), the shift—usually of a magnitude spectrum along the frequency axis, and then signal reconstruction via the [Griffin-Lim](http://musicweb.ucsd.edu/~sdubnov/CATbox/Reader/GriffinLimMSTFT.pdf)-algorithm ([Quora-explanation](https://www.quora.com/What-are-intuitive-explanations-of-the-Griffin-Lim-Algorithm) on how Griffin-Lim works).

The problem is that when we shift the magnitude spectrum, we do just that—and ignore the phase! Griffin-Lim tries to find a reasonable solution to find the correct phase when reconstructing the time domain signal, but it's often just that: a *reasonable* solution, not a *perfect* one. And that is why you hear this metallic twang. That's the phases of your signal not being quite right (also called "phasiness").

I believe your function call to `librosa` is perfectly alright. It may just not be the greatest implementation on earth. Give [PyRubberband](https://pyrubberband.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) a try. It's based on [Rubberband](https://breakfastquay.com/rubberband/) (a C++ library) and has a [good reputation](https://superpowered.com/free-open-source-time-stretching-pitch-shifting).

Comment: Ok, thank you!
Have you ever seen this error:
"RuntimeError: Failed to execute rubberband. Please verify that rubberband-cli is installed."?

Comment: No, sorry. I have not.